# GNU C/C++ Compiler change includes search order

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compilation, g++

As default the GNU C/C++ compiler looks up for include first into the directories specified with `-I` and then inside the standard system directories.

How can I force the compiler to inverse the search order?

At the moment I'm calling the compiler with the option `-nostdinc` set, which says the compiler to not search for header files inside the standard system directories. Then I'm passing the standard system directories using `-I` **before** all others includes.

Is there a better way to achieve that? Maybe a compiler option?

**UPDATE**: *as asked by the users, I add here some additional info to make tmy question clearer.*

[image: compilation setup]

I hope that the diagram can help to understand the setup and the reason why I have to inverse the search path order of the compiler.

When I try to compile my unit tests source file

```
CPPFLAGS          = -c -std=gnu++11 -v -g -O0 -pipe -Wall -MMD -MP -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
TEST_INCLUDE_PATH = -I$(GMOCK_DIR)/include -I$(GMOCK_DIR)/gtest/include -I$(ECOS_INSTALL_DIR)/include
```

Finally:

```
gcc $(CPPFLAGS) $(TEST_INCLUDE_PATH)
```

I got a lot of errors. By checking the include order of the compiler I remark that the compiler finds the header files of some system header files inside the wrong directories (in this case in eCos).

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 ../../../../Common/Implementation/TestLibraries/gmock-1.7.0/include
 ../../../../Common/Implementation/TestLibraries/gmock-1.7.0/gtest/include
 ../../Implementation/Build/eCos_install/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/i686-pc-cygwin
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include
 /usr/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../include/w32api
End of search list.
```

For info, my unit test looks at the moment like that:

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

class TestDummy : public ::testing::Test
{
  public:
    TestDummy() {}
};

TEST_F(TestDummy, ShouldFail)
{
    ASSERT_TRUE(false);
}
```

By inverting the order everything compiles fine:

```
CPPFLAGS            = -c -std=gnu++11 -v -g -O0 -pipe -Wall -MMD -MP -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -nostdinc
SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH = -I$(GCC_CYGWIN_PATH)/include/c++ ....
TEST_INCLUDE_PATH = -I$(GMOCK_DIR)/include -I$(GMOCK_DIR)/gtest/include -I$(ECOS_INSTALL_DIR)/include
```

Finally:

```
gcc $(CPPFLAGS) $(SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH) $(TEST_INCLUDE_PATH)

#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/i686-pc-cygwin
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include
 /usr/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../include/w32api
 ../../../../Common/Implementation/TestLibraries/gmock-1.7.0/include
 ../../../../Common/Implementation/TestLibraries/gmock-1.7.0/gtest/include
 ../../Implementation/Build/HostMCU_icb_jtag_install/include
End of search list.
```

Comment: Maybe option [`-isystem`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) can help you.

Comment: Use `<header>` for system (_e.g._ standard library _and external dependencies not part of your particular project_) headers and `"header"` for non-system (_e.g._ project) headers. To add system header paths, use `-isystem` as @piwi mentioned.

Comment: That doesn't work in my case. I have to build unit tests in Cygwin for some drivers of an embedded OS. So the `<header>` of the embedded OS are seen as the header files of Cygwin, which is wrong and won't even being found.

Comment: How does it "not work"? This is exactly what `-isystem` does, it appends to the _system_ include path. (In addition, should you not be using a cross-compiler, which presumably already has the correct system headers, if you are cross-compiling?)

Comment: The point is that the compiler looks up for header files first in `-I` directories, then in `-isystem` and then inside the standard system directories. And according to the GNU GCC documentation, `-isystem` is valid for `#include "file"` and `#include <file>` directives.

Comment: In that case I'm not sure I understand what your question is. Maybe you could include an example with the _expected_ and _actual_ paths for a few include directives? (Note: there's also `-iquote` and `-idirafter`, but since I can't understand what you're after I don't know if they will help.)

Comment: Also, how do you compile? Makefile, CMake...?

Comment: That's a strange thing to want to do. Design smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the eCos system include directory to be searched *after* the host system include directory, use `-idirafter`:

```
TEST_INCLUDE_PATH = -I$(GMOCK_DIR)/include -I$(GMOCK_DIR)/gtest/include -idirafter $(ECOS_INSTALL_DIR)/include
```

---

From [the GCC manual, chapter 12  “*Invocation*”](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html#Invocation):

> The lookup order is as follows:
>
> 1. For the quote form of the include directive, the directory of the current file is searched first.
> 2. For the quote form of the include directive, the directories specified by `-iquote` options are searched in left-to-right order, as they appear on the command line.
> 3. Directories specified with `-I` options are scanned in left-to-right order.
> 4. Directories specified with `-isystem` options are scanned in left-to-right order.
> 5. Standard system directories are scanned.
> 6. Directories specified with `-idirafter` options are scanned in left-to-right order.